# Checked property of the TCheckBox not found in Object Inspector

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe4

My Environment : C++ Builder XE4

I try to set default value as "true" for TCheckBox. 
I thought there was a property named "Checked" for TCheckBox. However, I cannot find "Checked" property in Object Inspector.

On the other hand, I can set "Checked" in code.

In this case, should I write code

```
CheckBox1->Checked = true;
```

for every TCheckBoxs, which need to be set true as default?

I am not quite sure about the older version of RadStudio or C++ Builder. But I think there was "Checked" property found in the C++ Builder 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is going on that you don't see it.  I have attached a screenshot of the Object Inspector for TCheckBox in C++ Builder XE5 Update 2.  However, this hasn't changed for as far back as I can remember.  As you can see, "Checked" is shown after "Caption" and before "Color".

If you can't figure it out, please post a screenshot of your object inspector for a TCheckBox

[image: Object Inspector in C++ Builder XE5 Update 2, for TCheckBox]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found the solution to this problem. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the Property tab of the Object Inspector, there is a setting for visible/invisible. Over the Property tab, right-click will show the "View" menu.

I set the "View" menu as "None", then set to "All". Then I can find the "Checked" Property for the TCheckBox.